# Pass object attribute to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a view I have a dropdownlistfor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CharterSchoolParameters", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedScenario.ID, Model.ScenarioList,
    new { onchange = "submit()"})
}
```

How do I pass the `SelectedScenario.ID` to the controller?

Here is the method definition I want to pass it to:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? selectedScenario_Id)
```

I'm not sure how to match the names.

Comment: you'll want to look up using View Models in MVC

Comment: I don't want to pass the entire model...just the single attribute.

Comment: try changing the parameter name to "id"

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: did you try it in caps? ID as per your property name? remember, MVC depends on the name of the property to be in the same case for the parameters. this is how the model binder works. maybe also try SelectedScenario_ID. How are you performing the POST?

Comment: Yes I tried in caps. Post is done with `new { onchange = "submit()" }`

Answer (score 0):

I think the name that asp.net mvc will bind for your parameter is `SelectedScenario_ID`, try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? SelectedScenario_ID)
{
   /// code...
}
```

On the other hand, you could use just a DropDownList, for sample:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CharterSchoolParameters", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.DropDownList("selectedScenarioId", Model.ScenarioList)
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? selectedScenarioId)
{
   /// code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default MVC route, you just need to change the parameter name passed to your controller to `id` as @Ahmed ilyas said.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    //code
}
```